# Netbeans does not recognize Flex CSS3 property

Tags: netbeans-8

I'm using netbeans 8.0.2 and I'm on a wordpres project.

Autocompletion of CSS is not active on my IDE, mainly flex property.

How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Speak to the Netbeans support team?

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249062